# Python Regular Expressions - extract every table cell content

Tags: python, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

If I have a string that looks something like...

```
"<tr><td>123</td><td>234</td>...<td>697</td></tr>"
```

Basically a table row with n cells.

What's the easiest way in python to get the values of each cell.  That is I just want the values "123", "234", "697" stored in a list or array or what ever is easiest.

I've tried to use regular expressions, when I use

```
re.match
```

I am not able to get it to find anything.  If I try with

```
re.search
```

I can only get the first cell.  But I want to get all the cells.  If I can't do this with n cells, how would you do it with a fixed number of cells?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If that markup is part of a larger set of markup, you should prefer a tool with a HTML parser.
One such tool is [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/).
Here's one way to find what you need using that tool:

```
>>> markup = '''"<tr><td>123</td><td>234</td>...<td>697</td></tr>"'''
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
>>> soup = bs(markup)
>>> for i in soup.find_all('td'):
...     print(i.text)
```

Result:

```
123
234
697
```

Comment: Can you recomend a good tutorial for BeautifulSoup so I can use it to get all the cells, row by row?  Thanks

Comment: The documentation is excellent and contains several examples: http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Answer (score 1):

Don't do this. Just use a proper HTML parser, and use something like xpath to get the elements you want.

A lot of people like lxml. For this task, you will probably want to use the BeautifulSoup backend, or use BeautifulSoup directly, because this is presumably not markup from a source known to generate well-formed, valid documents.

Comment: I prefer xml.etree.cElementTree

Comment: @Vayn That's great for known-good markup.

Comment: @Vayn: would you write an answer showing us how to use `xml.etree.cElementTree`? :D

Comment: @bemie I forgot xml.etree.cElementTree is only good for xhtml

Answer (score 1):

When using [lxml](https://lxml.de/), an element tree gets created. Each element in the element tree holds information about a tag.

```
from lxml import etree
root = etree.XML("<root><a x='123'>aText<b/><c/><b/></a></root>")
elements = root.findall(".//a")
tag = elements[0].tag
attr = elements[0].attrib
```